# Запрос данных Firebase ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase

У меня есть база с информацией

Путь

test/orders/***/тут стринговые значения(email, phone и т.д);

Как я могу получить все значение  с базы по ключам и вывести их на страницу в блок? Все это через ReactJs

```
<div key="">
 email
 phone
 address
 и т.д
</div>
```

Базу подключаю так

```
this.database = this.app.database().ref('test/orders/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно при обработке объекта использовать пересечение по ключам объекта. Примерно так:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       orders: null
    }
    this.ordersArrival = function(snapshot){
      this.setState({orders: snapshot.val()})
    }.bind(this);

   }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.database = firebase.database().ref('/test/orders');
    this.database.once("value").then(this.ordersArrival)
  }

  render() {
    let orders = this.state.orders;
    let outOrders = orders ? Object.keys(orders).map( (orderID, key) => (
      <li key={key}>
        email - {orders[orderID].email}, addres - {orders[orderID].address}
      </li>
    )) : "Loading...";

    return <div>
      <ul>
        {outOrders}
      </ul>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

[Ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/svkior/pen/YRaMxN)